# Passing variables to functions with variable length input arguments

Tags: matlab

[`blkdiag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/blkdiag.html) uses `varargin` to construct a block diagonal matrix from the input arguments (each matrix which needs to be inserted into the diagonal).

> `out = blkdiag(a,b,c,d,...)`, where `a, b, c, d, ...` are matrices,
>   outputs a block diagonal matrix of the form
>
> [image]

Suppose I had a cell array of matrices (or some other data structure) ; how would I feed this to a function like `blkdiag`?

Comment: Damn. Just figured out the answer. Ah well ...

Comment: @Phonon: That's generally not good form :)

Comment: It does however give good information to people looking for help on SO.

Comment: @Jacob: I disagree. I think it's perfectly ok to post a good answer to your own question.

Comment: @Jonas: Yep, definitely, but I personally prefer to do it if my answer is better/remains unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use {:} to expand it for the function:

```
blocks = cell(2);
blocks{1} = rand(2);
blocks{2} = rand(2);
out = blkdiag(blocks{:})
```

Answer:

```
out =

0.6787    0.7431         0         0
0.7577    0.3922         0         0
     0         0    0.6555    0.7060
     0         0    0.1712    0.0318
```